# Safari Extensions - can't get globalPage from safari object

Tags: javascript, safari-extension

i have problem obtaining `globalPage`from `safari.extension` inside injected script.

Every time i try to get it safari returns error in console:

`TypeError: Result of expression 'safari.extension.globalPage' [undefined] is not an object.`

Inside Global Page script i don't have problem obtaining it.

Does any one of you know how to resolve this issue ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly access globalPage from an injected script; you have to use message passing to access any globalPage objects. Read [this section](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/MessagesandProxies/MessagesandProxies.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009977-CH14-SW1) of the Safari Extensions Dev Guide. Comment if you need tips.